# How to easily test microphones in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microphone

Is there any way to speak something and quickly listen to my voices?

Basically I saw some graph showing up on sound properties. However, I can't listen to my voice. Screen capture software like camtasia produces video that does not contain my voices. I just want to trace down what's wrong.

Is my headset working at all? I can't even call anyone so not to bother them. I can't skype my own smartphones because the skype id is the same.

I am frustrated. All I want is to say something to microphone and listen it back.

Comment: Open up the sound recorder, record, then play back?

Comment: Tried. Got nothing. I think I tried that after asking this question.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I wanted to add that Skype has an echo / sound test service which will replay your voice to test your mic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also test your mic online.

https://www.onlinemictest.com/

Comment: A much better solution

Comment: Will edit to add another online site which also reproduces the recorded audio.

Comment: Link only answers aren't acceptable. Can you include example usage of this software? Please see [answer].

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the volume button down the bottom right of your taskbar and go to properties, go to the recording tab to see if you're microphone is there.

If it is there, click on it and see if you can set it to "default"

Check camtasia studios settings to make sure your mic is the default mic
[image]

To test if your Mic is working outside of Camtasia Studio.

1.) Hit Start

2.) Search for Voice Recorder ,

3.) Open the application and click on the microphone to start recording, when you stop the recording you can right click on the file and go to "file location" to open it and play it back.

This will determine if your mic is working, if not i would suggest looking for the latest drivers for your microphone.

Answer (score 0):

An Essential Tool for Checking Technical Issues on Your Microphone
https://www.mictest.co/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).